# Dynamicly change the input value of sum

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, laravel

Let say I have 2 input box to enter integer value and 1 input value for display the result of sum of 2 input box earlier.

How to make make not assigned input value default 0 integer..

Below are my code so far

```
<input type="text" id="txt1"  onkeyup="sum();" />
<input type="text" id="txt2"  onkeyup="sum();" />
<input type="text" id="txt3" />

function sum() {
  var txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById('txt1').value;
  var txtSecondNumberValue = document.getElementById('txt2').value;
  var result = parseInt(txtFirstNumberValue) + parseInt(txtSecondNumberValue);
  if (!isNaN(result)) {
    document.getElementById('txt3').value = result;
  }
}
```

Below are my demo.. Let say input 1 is value=1 and input 2=null, I wanna make Input 3 to be 1
http://jsfiddle.net/tLKLy/

Answer (score 0):

doing

```
document.getElementById('txt3').value = 0
```

should work.

if not, this will work too

```
$("input:txt3").val("0");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add default **`value`** attribute to the **`input`** tags and it should work.

```js
function sum() {
    var txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById('txt1').value;
    var txtSecondNumberValue = document.getElementById('txt2').value;
    var result = parseInt(txtFirstNumberValue) + parseInt(txtSecondNumberValue);
    if (!isNaN(result)) {
        document.getElementById('txt3').value = result;
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="0" id="txt1" onkeyup="sum();" />
<input type="text" value="0" id="txt2" onkeyup="sum();" />
<input type="text" id="txt3" />
```

Also you could do something like this, if you don't want to see the initial zeros. Basically parse the input fields and check if the sum is a Number.

```js
function sum() {
    let num1 = +(document.getElementById('txt1').value);
    let num2 = +(document.getElementById('txt2').value);
    let sum = num1 + num2;
    if (!isNaN(sum)) {
        document.getElementById('txt3').value = sum;
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txt1" onkeyup="sum();" />
<input type="text" id="txt2" onkeyup="sum();" />
<input type="text" id="txt3" />
```

Comment: Great idea. Will try that later with my full code

Answer (score 0):

```js
function sum() {
            var txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById('txt1').value;
            var txtSecondNumberValue = document.getElementById('txt2').value;
            var result = parseInt(txtFirstNumberValue) + parseInt(txtSecondNumberValue);
            if (!isNaN(result)) {
                document.getElementById('txt3').value = result;
            }
        }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txt1" value="0" onkeyup="sum();" />
<input type="text" id="txt2" value="0"  onkeyup="sum();" />
<input type="text" id="txt3" value="0"/>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/VIKAS_123/yotg8d64/